# Reading a class instance from the dB rather than the cache

Tags: hibernate, grails, caching

I am using grails 2.3.3 with Hibernate as the back end dB.

I would like to be able to get a class instance from the dB directly rather than the cache.

So in grails for example the code to access the instance is:

```
picturesShrInstance = PicturesShr.findByName(file.originalFilename)
```

All I get is the cache version.

any suggestions?

-mike

Comment: Why do you get the cached version? I mean, if you have previously executed the query and you execute it again, the data has not changed so it's ok the get the cached version (it's not necessary to go to the database). If you have changed the originalFilename and saved the object it's available in the hibernate cache and is also valid because you changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Disable hibernate cache.
2. Use the `refresh()` method on your domain instance(s).

The [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html) describes the `refresh()` method as:

> Re-reads the state of the given instance from the underlying database.
>   It is inadvisable to use this to implement long-running sessions that
>   span many business tasks. However this method is useful in certain
>   special circumstances.

Comment: Doing the query within `PicturesShr.withNewSession { }` might be another option

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thanks this does the trick: `picturesShrInstance.refresh()`. On Web Grails documentation pages - there used to be a really useful search bar at the bottom RH corner which has now disappeared and was very useful. Not sure if it's a browser setting or a grail web site setting I've inadvertently changed - or maybe it's been removed. Pity if that's the case -any ideas?

Comment: You could always use the single page version of the documentation and your browser's search feature http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html